# C# Sort Datagridview

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I would like to sort my `Datagridview` at the end of my `DownloadFileCompleted event`.
I tried the following source which is working if it's called on a `buttonClick event`, but it's not with my `DownloadFileCompleted event` and I don't understand why.

```
    // Does work
    private void bt_test_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dg_logiciel.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        dg_logiciel.Sort(dg_logiciel.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }

    // Does not work
    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // mycode
        dg_logiciel.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        dg_logiciel.Sort(dg_logiciel.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```

Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Is it not working as in throwing an error, or is it not being called at all?

Comment: I don't have any problem of compilation or error messages. I put a stagging point where I'm trying to sort and it seems my code is executed but my `DataGridView` is never updated

Comment: I think you would have to `invoke` the sorting calls as the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` is asynchronous and thus not on your UI thread. You may have to `Invoke` a call to `dg_logiciel` to refresh the `DataGridView` as well.

Comment: Would look like: 
`dg_logiciel.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() { dg_logiciel.Sort(...); });`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read the MSDN documentation about delegates and invoke method. Your idea seems good to solve my problem, but I don't understand these concepts, how does it work etc.. Could you explain me that on an easier way so I can try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `dg_logiciel` does not get updated is that the the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` method is being called asynchronously by whatever you're using to download in the background.  This means that the the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` method is being called by a different thread than the one that your `datagridview` is on. The `datagridview` is on the `UI Thread`, and the `client_DownloadFileCompleted` is being called by some `Worker Thread`.

To get around this problem you need to send something over to the `UI Thread` that tells it that it needs to perform some kind of action.

This can be accomplished by calling `<control>.Invoke(...)` as follows:

```
dg_logiciel.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate(){ dg_logiciel.Sort(dg_logiciel.Columns[1], ListSortDirectionAscending);});
```

This sends a message over to the `UI Thread` telling it call the `delegate` you're passing whenever it gets a chance. In this case the delegate just has one unnamed method inside of it and all that method does is call `dg_logiciel.Sort(...);` The `(MethodInvoker)` bit, for the sake of completeness, just casts the delegate as a `MethodInvoker` type.

A short simple answer can be found here: [How does Invoke work underneath?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/770502/4437524)

I hope that helps clear it up at least a little.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation and the time you spend helping me, it was really helpful, I appreciate!